# How to preserve the SQL output data types when I put it in Excel

Tags: php, sql-server, json, excel

I am trying to convert MSSQL output to JSON in PHP and for that I am trying to dump out the SQL result set into Excel, use `PHPExcel_IOFactory` to create an array and then use `json_encode` to convert to JSON.

I am able to populate the array fine, but all values are strings as I used text format for all columns in the Excel. If I don't, then I most of my data (which has dates, floats, big int) are not accurate.

Could I get some help in maybe preserving the data type when I simply copy paste the data into Excel or any other way that I can make this work?

Comment: Why not simply query the SQL Server data from php? There are plenty of php-SQL tutorials around.

Comment: I could. But my requirement prevents. I want production data to be fed into dev for my testing purpose.

Comment: Unless we are talking tons of data, I would get the Express version of SQL Server (which is free), build up the database, transfer over sample data, and go from there. It is a lot more efficient, and depending on how much data is needed, you can just transfer some across the network.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: I am on SQLServer 2012. And coming to the size of the data that I might be working on, that could go so far

Comment: You could create a macro in Excel that does all of the conversions for you - you would have to export the data, open Excel, and run the macro manually.

Comment: I second @LaughingVergil to use PHP directly. I don't know why you use Excel as medium. PHP's PDO or sqlserv API will preserve data types. If just to store data locally, use Access another database that works great with SQL Server, and of course adheres to RDBMS integrity -even links directly to *any* backend (nothing saved locally)!

Comment: @parfait I agree too. But that's how my requirement is. I can't use php on production env to call DB and then use json_encode on the result set. I would rather just have the result set directly fed into dev scenario to start debugging around.

Comment: Again, consider Access (which is actually just a GUI .exe console to the Jet/ACE SQL Engine, a data store installed on every Windows machine as .dll files) and can be used with PHP's PDO. You do not need the Office .exe installed. Access will rigidly maintain data types.